# It has the responsibility of integrating with a provider

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I am reading some documentation made by non-english speakers.

> This script has the responsibility of integrating with a sale provider
>   and converting its entities to our entities

I am not a native english speaker either, but it sounds weird to me. How would an actual native speaker say this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to say. Can you explain the context?

Comment: @RonaldSole It's just a description of what a programming script does.

Comment: In that case I shall leave it to a computer buff although you could simplify the sentence by saying either: The script integrates with... and converts its...    OR      The script is designed/programmed to integrate.....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the clearest possible sentence, but that's pretty much the way that native-speaker tech writers say it.

The script has a job, a purpose, a "responsibility". This responsibility involves communicating with "sale providers" -- whatever those are in this context -- and exchanging data, or "integrating". Apparently it reads bundles of data, "entities", from the sale provider and converts these bundles to its own format.